# Is there a way to use VBA to modify other VBA code?

Tags: vba

I don't know where to start with this. If there is a way, all I need is an object name or collection name, so I can look up the feature on Microsoft's site, and go from there. But, searching there directly didn't turn anything up.

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but you have to first change a setting in Excel to allow for it. "Trust access to the VBA project object model"

Comment: Thank you both! That's what I needed. But Mat, how do I mark your answer as "the answer"?

Comment: It's not an answer, just a comment... I didn't understand the question, hence why I commented on it. I'd just delete the question (and then read [ask] and [mcve] before posting the next one ;-)  ..glad it helped!

Comment: Oh, no, your answer was exactly what I needed (extensibility is the keyword I needed). So, you deserve the "answered" bump.
All I needed was a starting point. (I'll probably ask more questions later, but not until after I've at least tried some code.)

Comment: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx explains what you need to do

Comment: Thanks, Tim! I found that right away once I knew the keyword "extensibility" that Mat provided. (Hence why I want to credit him with the answer.) 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for the *VBE Extensibility Library*.

However note that depending on what you're *actually* trying to do ("modify other VBA code"), it may be very hard, if not impossible to implement.

The library will let you iterate modules, locate their members, pull the actual code into strings (from entire modules or just a given procedure)... but that's as granular as it gets.

If you're trying to do anything that requires understanding of the code's semantics, the VBIDE API won't be enough: you need a lexer and a parser for that... and I've yet to see a successful lexer/parser for VBA, written in VBA.

Good luck!